# QPainter draws text differetnly on different QPaintDevices

Tags: qt, qt4, qpainter, qt4.8

I have three `QPaintDevice`s, a `Qlabel` , a `QImage` and a `QPrinter`. When i try to draw non textual elements like rectangle , i got same output on all three devices. But when i try to draw text through `QPainter.drawText` the result on `QLabel` and `QImage` is same and `QPriner` output differs.(`QPrinter` output is a `PDF` file). actually the text size in `Qlabel` and `QImage` is bigger than text size in output `PDF` file.Waht is the cause of difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is coming most probably because of the resolution settings. See [enum QPrinter::PrinterMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtprintsupport/qprinter.html)

Also, QPrintSupport Class documentation states

> Note: When rendering text on a QPrinter device, it is important to
>   realize that the size of text, when specified in points, is
>   independent of the resolution specified for the device itself.
>   Therefore, it may be useful to specify the font size in pixels when
>   combining text with graphics to ensure that their relative sizes are
>   what you expect.

Comment: The difference is coming because of the resolution settings. The resolution of screen and print device must be equal.